# Skyrim's Windhelm House

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Okay, so I've beat the Blood on Ice mission and defeated the Imperial quest line, can I buy the house? Like, last I saw, Windhelm was burned, so can I still get it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's still possible to get the house. There are various conditions before you'll be allowed to buy it, some of which would be considered spoilers; mostly, it will involve some waiting for a new Jarl to be appointed.

Comment: I would be good to list the conditions if you can, you can put them in spoiler tags to avoid giving too much away at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can buy the house, you just need to: [SPOILERS]

> You need to talk to the new Jarl of Windhelm for any extra help. He'll tell you to help the people of Eastmarch. If you helped all 3 [Or 5] people, then return to the Jarl and go to Jorlief to buy the house from him.

So, it's possible even when siding with the Imperials.